# How to inject data in a html string in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a html string that contains a link. I need to add the attribute `rel="noopener"` for security purposes. The html string is injected through dangerouslySetInnerHtml:

```js
const Component = ({ message }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message }} />
    <div>
  );
};
```

The string looks like: `Hello check out <a href="https://my-link.com" target="_blank">this page</a>`

So the desired output would be: `Hello check out <a href="https://my-link.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">this page</a>`

How to do it?

Comment: Please post the code you use right now.. And what's stopping you from writing this html element explicitly (I mean, if it's not dynamic)?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the original post. But it's just a simple setDangerousInnerHtml div. I receive the html from an api to which I do not have access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const Component = ({ message }) => {

    function secureATags(html) {
        // Parse HTML
        let doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(html, "text/html")
        // Append attribute
        doc.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(entry => {
            entry.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener')
        })

        // Reserialize to HTML
        return doc.body.innerHTML
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: secureATags(message) }} />
        <div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Browser DOM to achieve this, as follows:

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");

div.innerHTML = 'Hello check out <a href="https://my-link.com" target="_blank">this page</a>';
div.childNodes[1].setAttribute("rel", "noopener");

console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

If the actual HTML text is more complex than in your example, then **`div.childNodes[1]`** will need to be replaced with code that looks for and selects the proper node. But even then (or especially then?), this is probably the easiest and most reliable way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using a function or component that puts it all together based on the data you send in? E.g.

```js
function App() {
  const linkBuilder = (textBefore, linkText, textAfter, href) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {textBefore}
        <a href={href} target="_blank">
          {linkText}
        </a>
        {textAfter}
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {linkBuilder("Hello check out ", "this page", "", "www.google.com")}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Also according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener) you don't need `rel=noopener` anymore if you use `target="_blank"`. But if it's necessary you can pass it in as a boolean and apply it on the function/component side.

Answer (score 0):

Direct use of `setDangerousInnerHtml` is strictly not recommended due to security issues.
you can use a plugin on `npmjs.org` pkgname: [React-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser) for injecting the html safely